# Can't recognize my Colorpage hr6 slim scanner

Tags: 11.10, drivers, scanner, sane

am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I have scanner called "genius colorpage hr6x slim" and when I run simple scan it just can't detected it; I tried "XSANE" but It gave the same answer!
When I run "dmesg" It give me this output:

> Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0458:2019 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) ColorPage-HR6X Slim

so what should I do I heard that some people put file from scanner Windows CD with ".usb" or ".bin" to "sane" folder so sane will detected!! but my CD doesn't have ".usb" but It have file with the name "layout.bin" how can I make this file to make ubuntu recognize my scanner?!
or is there's any software for scanner driver other than "sane"?
Thanks in advance (^_^).

Answer (score 1):

According to the sane-backends documentation and the source code in 12.04 for sane, your scanner is unsupported:

http://www.ok-solution.ca/upload/scanner.html

There's been a little bit of digging on what the scanner might be:

http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/genius-colorpage-hr6x.html

But so far, no code in gensys or any of the other backends and no udev rules for your scanner. Your only recourse is to find a programmer who can implement the required functionality for you. If you'd like to email me, we can talk about possible solutions.